# Expect script issue

Tags: bash, expect

I am trying to accomplish a simple job via expect. I want to create ssh keys using the "ssh-keygen" command on Linux VMs. My below expect code looks to be straight forward but it is not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh-keygen -t rsa
expect -exact "Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): "
send -- "\r"
expect -exact "Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): "
send -- "\r"
expect -exact "Enter same passphrase again: "
send -- "\r"
```

I do not want to use any pass phrase. hence typing `"\r"` for "Enter" key action.
I tried  running this code with `"#!/usr/bin/expect -d"`, and I find that it never matches the strings I have mentioned. something like below:

```
...
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match exact string "Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): "? no
....
```

SO I would presume as it is not able to match the pattern, my script is failing. 
The question is, why it is not able to match the pattern. I am using `"-exact"` and still it fails to match the patter. I tried to play around with `"-re"` but I think I am not good at TCL regex.

Could you help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The spawned program is likely sending more output than *exactly* what you're trying to match. That's why regular expression matching is so helpful.

Try this:

```
spawn ssh-keygen -t rsa
expect -re {Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): $}
send -- "\r"
expect -re {Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): $}
send -- "\r"
expect -re {Enter same passphrase again: $}
send -- "\r"
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn, you were right on the regex part. It worked for matching the pattern, but the debug of the expect command shows the pattern not matching. I dont care about the debug, as long as my script works. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you're exiting to quickly. This one works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh-keygen -t rsa
expect "Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): "
send  "\r"
expect "Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): "
send  "\r"
expect "Enter same passphrase again: "
send  "\r"
expect
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre, you are correct, I was exiting too early. I never realized that. My script is working absolutely fine after following your and Glenn's suggestion. Thanks to both you.