# Press enter, or write yes in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a `bash` script (called install_conda.sh), which installs Anaconda Cloud on my Ubuntu. I have downloaded the package using `wget`, i can make it run, but there are some things i can't figure out how to do.

1. 1st thing after i run the anaconda script is: "In order to continue the installation process, please review the license agreement.Please, press ENTER to continue". How do make my `install_conda.sh` to press that `Enter`?
2. After pressing enter, another thing appears: "Do you approve the license terms? [yes|no]". Here, i must type `yes`, and then press `Enter`. Again, how to do this?
3. Now, this thing appears: "Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location: /path/to/anaconda3 Press ENTER to confirm the location". Again i must press `Enter`...
4. In the end, i have to type `yes` again, for this: Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda3 install location to PATH in your /home/whatev/.bashrc ? [yes|no]".

2 days searching google didn't help. I've read something about an `xdotool`, but i want to avoid installing other stuff from the Internet, so bash only please.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried `expect`? [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729948/expect-script-issue)

Comment: As far as i know, in order to use `expect`, i have to install it first. I would like to avoid that, since the script might be used on computers without Internet access.

Comment: @tripleee, I can see why you marked this as duplicate, however, I find the answer is quite different from those you linked. It might be worth having this around and perhaps OP can re-word the original question to add some value to it. Just some thoughts...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am posting another answer, as this is probably closer to what you want.

Anaconda has a "[silent install](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/stable/user-guide/install/macos.html#install-macos-silent)" option. From the example on that page:

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-3.7.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @OliverBaumann!

Comment: @DavidBotezatu, if this helped, please accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

[`yes`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) does this for you nicely!
As for sending Enter, can you try sending the newline character `\n`?

Something like this perhaps:

```
#!/bin/bash
yes | bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Comment: Can you give me a precise example please? My script looks like this:

`$!/bin/bash
bash /tmp/Anaconda3-5.0.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh`

Comment: @DavidBotezatu `yes | install_conda.sh`

Comment: @Aserre it doesn't work... if i do `yes | install_conda.sh` it tells me `install_conda.sh: command not found`

Comment: @DavidBotezatu your script will be named differently. BTW, are you simply trying to automate running the default Anaconda installation script? Or have you actually **written** a script? If so, please post it!

Comment: @DavidBotezatu you must run it in this way: yes | bash install_conda.sh or: yes | ./install_conda.sh if your script have permissions.

Comment: @OliverBaumann I am trying to automate the installation of Anaconda3-5.0.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh - basically skip all those "Press enter" and "type yes" steps.